# how to pointcut to my custom throwable class which extends Exception class? (@aspect)

Tags: spring-boot, exception, aspectj, spring-logback, pointcut

I have  custom   SubscriberNotFoundException class which extends  Exception class.
I want  to  pointcut  its  some  methods  using  aspects  for catching exceptions and  logging  to file.

Here is my code:

```
    try {
          --------
        } 
        catch (SubscriberNotFoundException e) 
        { 
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .body(new Response(e.getCode(),  e.getMessage(), null));
        }
```

my  custom  class:

```
@ToString
@Getter   
public class SubscriberNotFoundException extends Exception {

    ------
}
```

The problem is that pointcut cannot handle this  methods of SubscriberNotFoundException  class.

I have tryed all case of  pointcut syntax, for example

```
@Pointcut("within(com.xyz.someapp.web..*)")
```

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.someapp.service.*.*(..))")
```

and  others, so i think that's not the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not pseudo code snippets out of context. Thank you. Please also explain if your target classes (the ones to be intercepted) are Spring components or non-Spring classes. That would determine if you can use Spring AOP or need native AspectJ.